# How do I make a function similar to print() but it waits afterwards?

Tags: python, function

I want to make a function for a text-based game in python where it prints out the parameter given and waits afterwards.

```
def say(string):
    time.sleep(1.5)
    return string
```

Comment: It looks like you just did, except for the printing part.

Comment: If you want to make a game most cmd games have the get input command. This will wait until the player provides an input. However, this may not be what you are looking for. Would you mind elaborating more the question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Periodical Poll and we can set up a condition , So until the condition is met it can wait .

```
import time

def wait_until(somepredicate, timeout, period=0.25, *args, **kwargs):
  mustend = time.time() + timeout
  while time.time() < mustend:
    if somepredicate(*args, **kwargs): return True
    time.sleep(period)
return False
```

Approach 2 :

We can use event Objects to wait for , here below is the Link which explains the same.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects